# How to implement load sharing for charging a Li-ion battery when charger outputs less current than consumed by load?

Tags: lithium-ion, charging, tp4056

I modified by TP4056 charge module like this [Adding power path to TP4056 solar battery charger and limit output voltage to 5.5 V or below](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/571720/adding-power-path-to-tp4056-solar-battery-charger-and-limit-output-voltage-to-5). But my charger's output is wind-powered so varies a lot, sometimes less than 5 mA, but constantly at 5 V. The problem is that when the power path circuit detects that 5 V is present, it disconnects the battery. But my load draws 50 mA, so the load can't function correctly.

Is there a good way or IC that enables pass-through charging? [Power banks made by "Voltaic"](https://voltaicsystems.com/v25/) do this but they are expensive. I don't know how to reproduce their functionality.

Comment: What's a "Voltaic battery"?

Comment: Existing product which has pass-through charging that works even at low charging currents https://voltaicsystems.com/v25/

Comment: That is not a "battery". It does have a battery inside, yes, but it is not a battery. It is a power bank. And "Voltaic" is a brand, not an adjective. I will modify your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 0):

Place a power resistor across the wind generator to drag down the voltage to below 5 V when the wind is slow.

Comment: I want to be able to charge even when input current is below 50mA. This also won't work because load current has peaks.